# Having Class 2 circuit together with class 1 circuit in regards to NEC

Tags: power-supply, power

There is often confusion between the IEC Class II power supply and an NEC Class 2 power supply. The former describes the insulation protection to shield users from an electric shock, while the latter concerns the installation of an electrical system. NEC Class 2 is used to assess wiring requirements between supply output and load input, considering factors like wire size, installation, and deration (the amount of current that wires carry).

I have a IEC Class II power supply (AC/DC) connected to class 1 wiring.

Power supply Specs:

Input: 90 ~ 305VAC
0.8A / 115VAC 0.4A / 230VAC 0.32A/277VAC

Output: 12v DC Voltage 5A

Load: 12V DC Voltage 3A

under NEC a "Class 2" circuit is a low-voltage circuit, and so the wiring between my power supply and the load is a Class 2 circuit. So can I have class 1 & Class 2 circuit in my case running together? Is there any Article in NEC apart from 725 which describes this?

Comment: Is the "case" you refer to a typical in-wall electrical box, usually used to mount electrical switches & outlets, or is it something else?

Comment: lighting pole on the street

Comment: Afaik if there's no physical isolation barrier between your incoming NEC Class 1 wiring and outgoing NEC Class 2 wiring, then you have to treat the whole installation as Class 1. Only if your PSU provides the physical isolation, and you maintain that isolation in your installation such that your Class 1 and Class 2 wiring doesn't share the same enclosure, can you treat the low-voltage as Class 2.

Comment: So if you just put [this](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/images/2118/MFG_IRM-60-ST.jpg) in a box, then everything is Class 1, even though the PSU provides 3kV isolation. But if you mount [this](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/KawAAOSw~Vhj~Ts9/s-l1600.jpg) to a knockout in a box, then inside the box is Class 1 and outside the box is Class 2. You're free to take the Class 2 output and feed it into another box, or even back into the same box *if that box has physical isolation between Class 1 and Class 2*.